# Memory limit in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, memory

What I'd like to know, more than the theoretical limit of the new ArcGIS Pro memory usage, is the real limit.

So, for users of ArcGIS pro, have you run a process using more than 4 GB of RAM, if so, how much? Has anyone experienced any memory limits at all?

Comment: Keep in mind desktop can be configured to run [64 bit background geoprocessing](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/analyze/executing-tools/64bit-background.htm).  That might resolve your error.

Comment: Although the two answers I got are interesting, they aren't addressing my question. Maybe it wasn't clear enough so I edited it. I know there's the 64-bit geoprocessing option but there are still some bottle necks that limit the amount of memory ArcGIS takes from the system. So what I want to know is if ArcGIS pro being a full 64-bit program experiences this handicaps.

Comment: one of mine grabbed everything available about 50gb of 64gb

Comment: ArcGIS Pro is 64 bit program. The amount of available memory it can consume is limited by the size of RAM and the size of your swap file. If you encounter out of memory error, increase the size of the swap file on your system, or install more RAM. I don't know of any tasks that would require 1 Tb of memory, but if you hit one, ensure that total size of RAM + swap file exceeds 1 Tb (has to exceed because other programs compete for the same space).

Answer (score 4):

I'm sorry, but you are mistaken.  32-bits can address 2^32 ([4 billion](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E32)) values, while 64-bits can address 2^64 ([18 quintillion](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E64)) values.  However, the underlying architecture of application memory partitions code into [code, data, stack, and heap](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/memory-layout-of-c-program/), which greatly lowers the amount of RAM which can be dynamically allocated.  There's also issues with memory use patterns, whereby a system with adequate amount of free memory does not have an adequate amount of ***contiguous*** heap to allocate requested storage (there's an entire *domain* in computer science to address optimal allocation strategies under these conditions).

There is no way to adequately address the real limits of 64-bit applications without a great deal of study in computer architecture theory.  The effective limit for memory addressing on a single host is an order of magnitude more complicated, due to the complications of multiprocessing and swap space.

Comment: Nice answer. Funny to think that 64-bit addresses will probably become too small one day.

Comment: I have a friend who, many years ago, mumbled, "Oh, you're still only using 64-bit longwords? Well, that can cramp your style."

Answer (score -1):

Normally ArcGIS Desktop is a 32-bit application, that has most of its commonly used tools ported to 64-bit applications. So while the desktop application is indeed locked at up to 3.2 GBytes of RAM, its geoprocessing service which is 64-bit can go a lot higher.

There is an issue if you use ArcGIS Desktop's tools in the GUI environment with Python: for example making a feature layer (to be able to use it in model builder), will be saved in the 32-bit app's memory. Frequent loading of large datasets as feature layers will clog up the memory and you might reach the maximum limit, however this is unlikely in day-to-day uses.

It would be nice if you could share the exact environment that created the "ERROR 010005: Unable to allocate memory." error message. What kind of operation were you performing, on what type of dataset?

Comment: The question is about the ArcGIS Pro architecture but this answer is about the ArcGIS 10.x for Desktop architecture.